# Zipping an existing file with Rubyzip

Tags: ruby

I would like to use rubyzip to archive "zip" an existing file:

c:\textfile.txt

to

textfile.zip

I know how to add a stream to a text file:

```
require 'zip/zip'

 Zip::ZipFile.open("mp.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
   |zipfile|
    zipfile.get_output_stream("text.txt") { |f| f.puts "Creating text file" }
    }
```

but not how to add an existing file to a zip. Thanks for your help

Comment: Apparently, you've to use streams. [Zippy](http://tore.darell.no/posts/zippy_rubyzip_for_dummies) may enable you to do what you want.

Comment: ok zippy looks promising, but I don't see a simple example that says find existing files and zip them. Do you know of one for zippy?

Answer (score 2):

This reads in the source file and writes it 1mb at a time to the zipfile.

I've been using something very similar in production for some time now.

```
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.open("mp.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    zipfile.get_output_stream("text.txt") do |out_file|
      File.open("text.txt") do |in_file|
        while blk = in_file.read(1024**2)
          out_file << blk
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I know it should be simple, but I'm new to Ruby. Would you mind showing how this could be modified in a ruby-ish way to loop through an array of file names?